# How to group components of css selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'd like to select tags whose class is `content` and are a general successor sibling of `.header` tags which have as descendant `.pagename > a[href="https://www.reddit.com/r/all"]`. However it doesn't seem possible to group as such:

```
(.header .pagename > a[href="https://www.reddit.com/r/all"]) ~ .content {}
```

What can I do?

Comment: Why are you trying to group? If you remove your parenthesis, it will do what you want.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't ask my question properly. I rephrased it so that it makes sense. @disinfor

Comment: You have issues with your markup that need fixing. You shouldn't need this kind of selector.

Comment: I think you're looking for the [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) selector, e.g. `.header:has(.pagename > a[href="https://www.reddit.com/r/all"]) ~ .conent`. Unfortunately this has basically [no browser support at all](https://caniuse.com/css-has), yet.